# Is the splash part of the Strike?

Tags: spells, damage, attack, pathfinder-2e

[Cry of Destruction](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=410) says:

> Each creature and unattended object in the area takes 1d8 sonic damage. **If you already dealt damage to an enemy this turn with a Strike** or spell, increase the damage dice from this spell to d12s.

While the character is unlikely to hit with a usual weapon, and 1 action spells are rare, a bomb seems to be an easy solution.

Is the splash damage part of the Strike, so will it trigger the damage increase?

Comment: Bombs + Cry of Destruction... now *that's* a combo. Keeping this in my book of tricks!

Comment: Essentially requires spellcasting and Martial weapon proficiency (so Warpriest). Seems fair enough when there are already spells that use d12 available

Comment: It is actually an Oracle with Champion Dedication. Trying to decide between Weapon Proficiency (for bombs), and Harm as 1 action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, the splash damage is dealt by the strike

You made a strike, and the damage is dealt by this strike. The splash damage rules modify when you get to apply damage, compared to a normal strike, but nowhere do they state that the damage it does not count as dealt by the strike that caused it.

You can see this, because the splash damage is still dependent on the result of your strike: if your strike fails critically, you deal no damage. You can also see it from the splash damage being added together with other damage the strike deals, before the next steps in the procedure, applying weaknesses or resistances.

For reference, the Splash trait says:

> If an attack with a splash weapon fails, succeeds, or critically succeeds, all creatures within 5 feet of the target (including the target) take the listed splash damage. On a failure (but not a critical failure), the target of the attack still takes the splash damage. Add splash damage together with the initial damage against the target before applying the target’s weaknesses or resistances.